# Django Manage.py Migrate from Google Managed VM Dockerfile - How?

Tags: django, google-cloud-sql, dockerfile, managed-vm, google-managed-vm

I'm working on a simple implementation of Django hosted on Google's Managed VM service, backed by Google Cloud SQL. I'm able to deploy my application just fine, but when I try to issue some Django manage.py commands within the Dockerfile, I get errors.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python

RUN virtualenv /venv -p python3.4

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /venv
ENV PATH /venv/bin:$PATH

# Install dependencies.
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add application code.
ADD . /app

# Overwrite the settings file with the PROD variant.
ADD my_app/settings_prod.py /app/my_app/settings.py

WORKDIR /app

RUN python manage.py migrate --noinput

# Use Gunicorn to serve the application.
CMD gunicorn --pythonpath ./my_app  -b :$PORT --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_app.settings my_app.wsgi
# [END docker]
```

Pretty basic. If I exclude the `RUN python manage.py migrate --noinput` line, and deploy using the GCloud tool, everything works fine. If I then log onto the VM, I can issue the `manage.py migrate` command without issue.

However, in the interest of simplifying deployment, I'd really like to be able to issue Django manage.py commands from the Dockerfile. At present, I get the following error if the `manage.py` statement is included:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/my_app:us-central1:my_app_prod_00' (2)")

Seems like a simple enough error, but it has me stumped, because the connection is certainly valid. As I said, if I deploy without issuing the `manage.py` command, everything works fine. Django can connect to the database, and I can issue the command manually on the VM.

I wondering if the reason for my problem is that the sql proxy (`cloudsql/`) doesn't exist when the Dockerfile is being deployed. If so, how do I get around this?

I'm new to Docker (this being my first attempt) and newish to Django, so I'm unsure of what the correct approach is for handling a deployment of this nature. Should I instead be positioning this command elsewhere?

Comment: Try adding "-v /cloudsql:/cloudsql" to the "docker run" command

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. It at least allowed me to see the full exception dump. There was only the one exception though, as listed above, so it didn't leave me with any new information. Still not sure why I can't connect through the socket until after the dockerfile has completed.

Comment: Can you show the command you are using to run the container? "-v /cloudsql:/cloudsql" should expose the sockets to the container.

Comment: @Vadim - Sorry, I misunderstood your suggestion. I added verbosity to the python command to get a more detailed trace. I'm using Google Managed VMs, so the execution of the docker command is managed by them. I just supply the dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps involved in deploying the application.

In the first step, the Dockerfile is used to build the image, which can happen on your machine or on another machine.

In the second step, the created docker image is executed on the Managed VM.

The RUN instruction is executed when the image is being **built**, not when it's being run.

You should move manage.py to the CMD command, which is run when the image is being **run**.

```
CMD python manage.py migrate --noinput && gunicorn --pythonpath ./my_app  -b :$PORT --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_app.settings my_app.wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Thanks for the additional clarity you added.